# SSO for Laravel and moodle applications from WordPress

Tags: laravel, wordpress, single-sign-on, moodle

I am in a need to have single sign-on (SSO) on my applications.

Basically, I have three applications in different directories. I have a WordPress(ecommerce) site running in the main folder of my domain and a Laravel application in a directory and a moodle(lms) application in a directory.

The idea is if I log into my WordPress site, I don't need to sign in on the other two applications and able to access the Laravel and moodle applications.

**I will give access to moodle pages from laravel app. What is the best approach to achieve this?**

Answer (score 0):

Moodle has OAuth2, I'm guessing Wordpress has it too?

https://docs.moodle.org/311/en/OAuth_2_authentication

So maybe use an oauth2 server, eg Okta or OneLogin